# Python 2.7 - Black Jack IndexErrors, and more...

Tags: python

I posted earlier yesterday, but now completely revised my code (using a chunk of the framework from someone else's iteration of it, with a bunch of stuff added. Experiencing some issues though. Take a look.)

```
import random as r
deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]*4
dealer = []
player = []
decision = "y"
player_money = 5000
dealer_money = 5000
pot = 0
total = 0

def showHand():
    hand = 0
    for i in player: hand += i #Tally up the total
    print "The dealer is showing a %d" % dealer[0]
    print "Your hand totals: %d (%s)" % (hand, player)
    print "You have $", player_money
    print "The dealer has $", dealer_money
    print "The pot right now is $", pot
    print "*** *** ***"

def setup():
    for i in range(2):
        dealDealer = deck[r.randint(1, len(deck)-1)]
        dealPlayer = deck[r.randint(1, len(deck)-1)]
        dealer.append(dealDealer)
        player.append(dealPlayer)
        deck.pop(dealDealer)
        deck.pop(dealPlayer)

menu = raw_input("Welcome to Black Jack! What would you like to do? \n a) Start a new game \n b) Rules \n c) Quit").lower()
if menu == 'a':
    setup()
    while decision != 'q':
        showHand()
        decision = raw_input(" [B]et [H]it [S]tand [Q]uit: ").lower()
        #set up betting system, as well as enemy AI
        if decision == 'b':
            bet = input("How much will you bet? ($)")
            player_money = player_money - bet
            pot = pot + bet
            total = total + bet
            print "*** *** ***"
            print "You bet $", bet, "!"
            hand = 0
            for i in dealer: hand += i
            if hand > 1:
                dealer_bet = bet
                dealer_money = dealer_money - dealer_bet
                pot = pot + dealer_bet
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "The dealer calls your bet!"
                print "*** *** ***"
                total = total + dealer_bet
            elif dealer_money <= bet:
                dealer_bet = dealer_money
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "The dealer calls your bet!"
                print "*** *** ***"
                pot = pot + dealer_bet
                total = total + dealer_bet


            elif hand > 14:
                dealer_bet = bet + 1.25*bet
                dealer_money = dealer_money - dealer_bet
                pot = pot + dealer_bet
                total = total + dealer_bet
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "The dealer raises your bet to $", dealer_bet, "!"
                print "*** *** ***"
            elif dealer_money < bet:
                dealer_bet = dealer_money
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "The dealer goes all in!"
                print "*** *** ***"
                pot = pot + dealer_bet
                total = total+ dealer_bet


            elif hand > 20:
                dealer_bet = bet + 1.5*bet
                dealer_money = dealer_money - dealer_bet
                pot = pot + dealer_bet
                total = total + dealer_bet
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "The dealer raises $", dealer_bet, "!"
                print "*** *** ***"
            elif dealer_money < 1.5*bet:
                dealer_bet = dealer_money
                pot = pot + dealer_bet
                total = total + dealer_bet
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "The dealer went all in!"
                print "*** *** ***"


        #set up hit system, as well as enemy AI for if they will hit/stand
        if decision == 'h':
            dealPlayer = deck[r.randint(1, len(deck)-1)]
            player.append(dealPlayer)
            deck.pop(dealPlayer)
            hand = 0
            print "You take a hit! You received a", dealPlayer

            for i in dealer: hand += i
            if hand < 15:   #Dealer AI.
                dealDealer = deck[r.randint(1, len(deck)-1)]
                dealer.append(dealDealer)
                deck.pop(dealDealer)
                print "Opponent takes a hit!"
                print "*** *** ***"

            elif hand >= 15:   #Dealer AI.
                print "Opponent stands. Mans are playing it safe."
                print "*** *** ***"

            hand = 0
            for i in player: hand += i
            if hand > 21:
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "Bust! You went over 21."
                print "*** *** ***"
                player = []     #Clear player hand
                dealer = []     #Clear dealer's hand
                setup()         #Run the setup again
                pot = 0
                dealer_money += total
                total = 0

            hand = 0
            for i in dealer: hand +=i
            if hand > 21:
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "Dealer Busts! You win $", total, "!"
                print "*** *** ***"
                player = []
                dealer = []
                setup()
                pot = 0
                player_money += total
                total = 0


        elif decision == 's':
            dealerHand = 0           #Dealer's hand total
            playerHand = 0           #Player's hand total
            for i in dealer: dealerHand += i
            for i in player: playerHand += i
            #If player hand is greater than dealer's hand, they win.
            if playerHand > dealerHand:
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "You had a higher total than the dealer! You just won mon!"
                print "You earned $", total, "!"
                print "*** *** ***"
                player = []
                setup()
                pot = 0
                player_money += total
                total = 0

            else:
                print "*** *** ***"
                print "The dealer had a higher total! You just lost mon!"
                print "*** *** ***"
                dealer = []
                player = []
                pot = 0
                dealer_money += total
                total = 0

            if player_money == 0:
                    print "You're broke! GG!"
                    print "*** *** ***"
                    break

            elif dealer_money <= 0:
                    print "Dealer is broke! You won bro!!!"
                    print "*** *** ***"
                    break
elif menu == 'b':
    choice = raw_input("Welcome to Black Jack, a famous card game in the casinos. \n The goal is to have a higher card sum than the dealer. \n Players are given two cards at the beginning of each round. \n The player can then choose to bet money, hit (receive another card), or stand (will end the round, tally up the player and dealer's card sums, and determine the winner of the round). \n Remember that if your card sum exceeds 21, you will automatically lose the round! You cannot go over 21. \n If you or the dealer run out of money, the game will end. \n Would you like to start a game now? (y/n)")
    if choice == 'y':
        menu == 'a'
    elif choice == 'n':
        menu == 'a'

elif menu == 'c':
    decision = 'q'
    print "Goodbye~"
```

Two main issues. Sometimes, when I stand and the round ends, I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Black Jack Revision.py", line 43, in <module>
    showHand()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Black Jack Revision.py", line 23, in showHand
    print "The dealer is showing a %d" % dealer[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Also, I have not found a way to get the instructions to loop back to the main menu. I didn't make menu a function because it messed around too much with local variables no longer working.

Assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to use `setup()` in the else statement in `decision == 's'`? `dealer` will be empty when it goes back up to `showHand()`, which tries to access `dealer[0]`.

```
        else:
            print "*** *** ***"
            print "The dealer had a higher total! You just lost mon!"
            print "*** *** ***"
            dealer = []
            player = []
            #here
            pot = 0
            dealer_money += total
            total = 0
```

After I added that change, I hit stand ("S") a few times and your error did not replicate. However a new error did occur after hitting it a few times.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SO.py", line 168, in <module>
  setup()
File "SO.py", line 27, in setup
  deck.pop(dealDealer)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

The deck is never reinitialized in any situation.

Comment: @user3211205 Here is a hint, `deck.pop(dealDealer)` doesn't remove the value that is `dealDealer`, it removes that position of the list. 
If dealer = [11,12,13,14,15,16], then `dealer.pop(5)` will remove 16. If we repeat `dealer.pop(5)`, then we will get the `indexError` because position 5 does not exist anymore. Here is the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: Sorry, no clue... I'm new to this.

Comment: @user3211205 `setup()` will continue to shorten `deck` and at some point, it will try to pop out a position in `deck` that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks, realized that shortly after learning what pop does. Decided it was unnecessary for the game to eventually terminate on its own, so I got rid of pop as a whole. The deck is now unlimited.